# Any way to change specific data in a column e.g Mr to Dr which contains a name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to change the Titles of 'doctors' in a database and was just wondering was there a SQL query which I could run to change them.

[The column im trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca4iM.png)

What I am asking is that there is any way I can update the column to add a 'Dr' infront of the names to replace the 'Miss','Mr' etc.

I'm thinking about using a SQL Statement containing the wildcard function to update it but not sure it would change the specifics.

Thanks,

Karl

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE` option

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'Mr.', 'Dr.')
WHERE column_name LIKE 'Mr.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Update myTable
set name = replace(replace(name,'Miss ','Dr '),'Mr ','Dr ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest doing:

```
update t
    set col = stuff(col, 1, charindex(' ', col + ' '), 'Dr');
```

This *only* replaces the first word in the string.  You might want to be extra careful and add a `where` clause.

```
update t
    set col = stuff(col, 1, charindex(' ', col + ' '), 'Dr') 
    where col like 'Miss %' or col like 'Mr %' or
          col like 'Mrs %' or col like 'Ms %';
```

The problem with `replace()` is that it replaces all occurrences in the string.  Although the honorifics are unlikely to be in a name, you could have names like "Missy Elliott".

Comment: That's very useful - thank you Gordon. It makes a lot of sense!